# Get min googlePrice for each productId

Tags: sql, mysql, navicat

I have got next SQL query

`select * from ( select * from prices as p order by p.productId, p.googlePrice ) as t`

It returns next result

[Result of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCtjj.png)

I want to get the same table for each productId with min googlePrices

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbqUO.png)

I have tried to use group by, having... something like this:

`select t.productId, MIN(t.googlePrice), t.priceRaw, t.id, t.title from prices t group by t.productId`

But it isn't a result that I need.

I need a table with records for each productId min googlePrice. I've marked records that I need with green line.

[Result that I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvpAc.png)

I can't solve the task. Help please!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a windows function, partitioning by productId. Based on your question, not sure if you want a new column with the min_price, or rather, just the records with the min price. Both options below.

```
create table prices (
  id integer, 
  productId integer, 
  title varchar(20), 
  googlePrice integer
  );
  
insert into prices values 
(1, 22222, 'ABC', 20), 
(2, 22222, 'CDE', 50), 
(3, 22222, 'ZZZZ', 10), 
(4, 888, 'DDDD', 5);
```

---

**Query #1** (if you just want another column and display all rows)

```
select *,
 min(googlePrice) over (partition by productId) as min_price
from prices;
```

| id | productId | title | googlePrice | min_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 888 | DDDD | 5 | 5 |
| 1 | 22222 | ABC | 20 | 10 |
| 2 | 22222 | CDE | 50 | 10 |
| 3 | 22222 | ZZZZ | 10 | 10 |

---

**Query #2** (if you want to display only the min rows)

```
select *
from (
 select *,
  row_number() over (partition by productId order by googlePrice) as mp
 from prices
  )z
where mp = 1;
```

| id | productId | title | googlePrice | mp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 888 | DDDD | 5 | 1 |
| 3 | 22222 | ZZZZ | 10 | 1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oLDWb4R9fzp8JT5z4LaevM/1)

**UPDATE**
If you have **ties** for lowest price by productId, and want to display ALL with the lowest value, then use `RANK()` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: Oh my God... I've never used this constructions before... I'll try. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Eltar Should this answer suffice, then please consider marking the Accept answer flag, thank you.

Comment: I'd like to do it but I can't. I haven't got 15 reputations to mark you answer useful... I'm very sorry!

Comment: Marking as useful is different. There's an "accept" flag which does not require reputation.